# Drupal cron.php failing

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

I ran drupal cron.php to see what is failing. It gave me an "Internal Server Error" 500. It is not the execution time because I used set_time_limit and raised the runtime to  a ridiculously high number. Does anyone know what the problem is? It doesn't run for too long either.

Comment: Check your webserver's error logs.

Comment: Possibly hitting the memory limit?

Comment: Got to `admin/reports/dblog` and check for error messages

Comment: Do you have any custom modules installed? A bag coded module might be the cause. Also, if you have used php filter inside node's body might result in cron failing to run. Can you make changes to the modules configuration page (enable / disable a module)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the Php Memory limit in the ini.php